# S3 jpeg Image download instead of Displaying in Chrome

Tags: image, amazon-s3, file-upload, jpeg, mime-types

Although I have the content-type set to "image/jpeg" in my Metadata settings for my "55-user.jpg" image in my S3 bucket, clicking the Object URL downloads the image instead of displaying it in my chrome browser.;

https://mybucketbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/55-user.jpg

[image: S3 Metatdata settings]

Oddly it works fine in Firefox or Microsoft Edge.

How can I get it to display as an image instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to `inline`.